# How can I use a while loop in Kotlin to iterate through a BufferedReader and append to a StringBuilder?

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is some code I ported over from Java:

```
var audioDataString = ""
        val jsonReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(context.resources.openRawResource(resourceName)))
        val jsonBuilder = StringBuilder()
        var line: String? = null
        while ((line = jsonReader.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonBuilder.append(line).append("")
        }
```

The "*(line = jsonReader.readLine())"* gives me the following error: Assingments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context.

How do I do this correctly in Kotlin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

There are [many different extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/index.html#extensions-for-external-classes) in the Kotlin standard library you could make use of here for inputstreams, files, readers, etc. For this use case, [`Reader.forEachLine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/for-each-line.html) would be the simplest to use:

```
jsonReader.forEachLine { line ->
    jsonBuilder.append(line)
}
```

This lets you process an `Reader` line by line, and it automatically closes the `Reader` when the iteration is over.

You might also want to take a look at [`readLines`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/read-lines.html), [`lineSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-buffered-reader/line-sequence.html), and [`useLines`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-reader/use-lines.html) which could help you in more complex situations.

Comment: I didn't know this existed! I should convert my code.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the best way I've found to do this is with a `while(true)`:

```
var audioDataString = ""
        val jsonReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(context.resources.openRawResource(resourceName)))
        val jsonBuilder = StringBuilder()
        var line: String? = null
        while (true) {
            line = jsonReader.readLine() ?: break
            jsonBuilder.append(line).append("")
        }
```

Just in case you don't know, the elvis operator (`?:`) checks if what's on the left is `null` and carries out the action on the right if it is.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, variable assignments are not considered expressions. But this is actually intended to improve the code quality. All you need is to create an iterable reader object. And you can do that using the `generateSequence` function:

```kotlin
for (line in generateSequence(::readLine)) {
    /** here you can use the line just read,
     *  and you can even add other line reading
     *  calls within this block */
}
```

This works for any reader that signalizes the end of sequence with null. The above example reads from stdin, but `jsonReader::readLine` would work as well.